# Get component ref from Vue @click event

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Hopefully a simple one to answer, but I cannot get an HTML reference to the component that triggers an `@click` event in vue after much searching. So I have a custom component in a list

```
<ion-list lines="none" v-for="item in uiPosts" :key="item.createdAt">
  <ion-item v-if="!item.skipped" class="ion-no-padding">
   <SummaryCard class="summary" 
                :post=item 
                @click="handleCardClick"
                ... blah blah blah
```

and a simple handler

```
const handleCardClick = async (e : Event) => {
   ... stuff
  console.log(e.target); // something like the card title but not the actual card
}
```

And `e.target` just gives me granular sub elements for the card like the heading or subheading. Same if I attach `@click` event to the `ion-item` in the list. I just want a ref to the thing I actually attach the click event to so I can make sure it is fully scrolled into view when clicked.

Comment: i would simply pass it to the function like so `@click="handleCardClick(item, $event)"`, and adjust the function to be : `async (item: MyItem, e: Event) => {}`

Comment: But `MyItem` is not a `HTMLElement` type, so I cannot use `scrollIntoView(..)` on it @Lk77

Comment: Yes but i'm sure you have an id or something that can be used as a ref to retrieve it, like `:ref="'item-'+item.id"` on the tag, and retrieve it using `this.$refs['item-' + item.id].$el`

Comment: Ok. That put me on the correct trail @Lk77. Thanks

Comment: You can take a look at [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: @Duannx that's the answer I was looking for. Write that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @learnvst I saw you already mentioned it in your answer. It is ok, just move that section to the top of your answer for other people easier to scan.

Comment: @Dunnax completed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from @Duannx, the actual simple answer is just to use `event.currentTarget`. Then in typescript . . .

```
const handleCardClick = async (e: Event) => {
  const el = e.currentTarget as HTMLDivElement
  el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
}
```

**Some more janky ways below just if you stumble upon this question . . .**

Ok. So from the [vue 3 docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) (with the composition API switch toggled!!!).

Callback like this:

```
const cardRefs = ref<HTMLDivElement[]>([])

const handleCardClick = async (idx: number) => {
  const el = cardRefs.value[idx];
  el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end"});
}
```

Template like this:

```
     <ion-list lines="none">
        <div v-for="(item, idx) in uiPosts" :key="item.createdAt" ref="cardRefs" @click.capture="handleCardClick(idx)">
          <ion-item v-if="!item.skipped" class="ion-no-padding" >
            <SummaryCard class="summary" 
            :post=item 
            ...
```

Which solves the challenge in the original question

**EDIT:**

There is a better way . . because from the docs "It should be noted that the ref array does not guarantee the same order as the source array." . . and this definitely gets weird when you have something like an infinite list.

Instead of passing the callback from the infinite list, derive it from the event. This is more robust

```
const handleCardClick = async (e: Event) => {     
    const idx = cardRefs.value.findIndex((element)=>{return element.contains(e.target as HTMLElement)})                 
    cardRefs.value[idx].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
}
```